# How to remain the previous text box value on button click

Tags: javascript

Hello Friends
I am facing some problem or can say not figure out any help regard this so please help me
There is button having name Add Text when I click that button it display a text box when i enter some text in this text box it display the entered text below.when I click again Add Text button  then previous one textbox seems empty i don't want this.

1.) My requirement is when I click Add Text button second time it doesn't empty the previous textbox.

2.) when i click the B button then it convert the text to bold.Right now its working for one text i want when i select particular text and click B button it convert the particular selected text to bold. 
These are my two problem.Please reply if anybody having the solution of my problem.
Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var i=0;
   function add_input()
        {
          if(i!=6){
              var d=document.getElementById('div');

           d.innerHTML+="<input type='text'  name='addtext"+i+"' id='addtext"+i+"'onkeyup='copy("+i+")'><br></br>";
                 i++;
                 }

        }
  function copy(j){

           var mm = 'addtext'+j;
           var divid = 'newcontent'+j;
           var s1=document.getElementById(mm).value;

           /*var s2=document.getElementById('newcontent'+j);*/
           var s2=document.getElementById('newcontent'+j);

           s2.innerHTML=s1;


            }
          </script>


      <script type="text/javascript">
          function f2() {

               if(document.getElementById('newcontent0').style.fontWeight =='bold')
                    {
                         document.getElementById('newcontent0').style.fontWeight = 'normal';
                    }
                   else if(document.getElementById('newcontent0').style.fontWeight =='normal')
                     {
                        document.getElementById('newcontent0').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
                      }
                  else if(document.getElementById('newcontent0').style.fontWeight =='')
                     {
                        document.getElementById('newcontent0').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
                      }
              }
             </script>

     <input  type="button" value="Add Text" onclick="add_input()"  />
     <input type="button"  value="B"  onclick="f2()"/> 
     <div id="div"></div>
     <div id="newcontent0"  style="padding:0px;margin:0px;"></div>
     <div id="newcontent1"  style="padding:0px;margin:0px;"></div>
     <div id="newcontent2"  style="padding:0px;margin:0px;"></div>
     <div id="newcontent3"  style="padding:0px;margin:0px;"></div>
     <div id="newcontent4"  style="padding:0px;margin:0px;"></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.) My requirement is when I click Add Text button second time it doesn't
>   empty the previous textbox.

This happens because you replace the `innerHTML`. Any text you have typed into the input field will not be retained, because it's not part of the new `innerHTML`.

To prevent this from happening, you can manipulate the DOM instead. It may be a bit more code and theoretically somewhat slower, but in this case that's not something you need to worry about.

> 2.) when i click the B button then it convert the text to bold.Right now its
>   working for one text i want when i
>   select particular text and click B
>   button it convert the particular
>   selected text to bold.

This one is a little trickier. We need to remember which input field was last selected, so that `f2()` can set the fontWeight of the correct element. You can do that by using the `onblur` event of the input elements and having a variable `lastFocused` remembering which one was last selected.

All in all, something like this should work (try here: http://jsfiddle.net/2euLZ/) :

```
var i = 0;
var lastFocused = null;

function add_input()
{
    if(i != 6){
        var d=document.getElementById('div');
        var newId    = i;

        var newInput = document.createElement("input");
        newInput.type    = "text";
        newInput.name    = "addtext" + i;
        newInput.id      = "addtext" + i;
        newInput.onkeyup = function() { copy(newId); };
        newInput.onblur  = function() { lastFocused = newId; };

        d.appendChild(newInput);
        d.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        i++;
    }
}

function copy(j)
{
       var s1 = document.getElementById('addtext'+j);
       var s2 = document.getElementById('newcontent'+j);
       s2.innerHTML = s1.value;
}

function f2() {
    var target = document.getElementById("newcontent" + lastFocused);

    var newFontWeight = "bold";
    if(target.style.fontWeight == "bold")
        newFontWeight = "normal";

    target.style.fontWeight = newFontWeight;
}
```

Comment: Hello ur code working but now my functionality not work.Entered text not be displaye below the textbox .Thanks for reply

Comment: I had made a small mistake in the first attempt. Fixed it now, and added a suggestion for your second question.

Comment: Sir if u there please reply me its urgent.Thanks

Comment: No ,its work.I m facing some other problem but it resolved.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will solve you first problem

```
function add_input()
        {
          if(i!=6){
              var d=document.getElementById('div');
          p = document.createElement("input");

           p.type="text";
           p.name="addtext"+i ;
           p.id="addtext"+i ;
           p.setAttribute('onkeyup','copy('+i+')');    
           br = document.createElement("<br>");
           d.appendChild(p);
           d.appendChild(br);
                 i++;
                 }

        }
```

for second check out this link may help you
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/HTML/CapturingaTextSelection.htm

Comment: Thanks for reply sir.its working ,how to add <br> at the end of each text box

Comment: in the left of this answer there are two arrows and 0 clicking the up arrow means you are upvoting the answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a consequence of resetting the innerHTML every time, which has the side effect of resetting the contents of the text boxes. You probably did not intend to delete and recreate *all* the text boxes when just one is added. Instead, use DOM methods to manually build nodes and insert them:

```
var inp = document.createElement('input');
inp.name = 'addtext' + i;
inp.id = 'addtext' + i;
inp.onkeyup = function() {
    copy(this.id.slice(7));
};
d.appendChild(inp);
d.appendChild(document.createElement('br');
```

JavaScript libraries can make this easier. In fact, jQuery can render your exact innerHTML generation attempt functional using only `$('#div').append('your html code here')`. If you do not use jQuery, [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML) might suffice.

As far as getting the selected text goes, take a look at the [fieldSelection](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fieldselection) code. It's old and may not work with current versions of jQuery, but that's roughly it. If you are also planning on implementing italic text, underlining, *etc.*, you may want to consider a [contentEditable div](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand/) as used by the major in-browser rich text editing scripts such as [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) (although that particular one uses an iframe).